# General Question about Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

So I saw a video about the Knapsnack problem, which can be solved recursively as well as using dynamic programming. The gist I got about dynamic programming is that it's nothing more than a dictionary, list or collectively a **record** of stuff we have already computed so we don't have to compute it again.

Is that what dynamic programming is all about? Performing **record keeping** and using when necessary?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what dynamic programing is.

Comment: Yes, in very general terms this is it.

Comment: Isn’t this off-topic? Try CS Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia: "*Dynamic Programming is a method for solving a complex problem by breaking it down into a collection of simpler subproblems, solving each of those subproblems just once, and storing their solutions using a memory-based data structure (array, map,etc).*"

Like with recursive algorithms, the key is breaking down the problem in smaller sub-problems, using efficient data-structures to help you in the task.

So, in a nutshell, it is exactly about efficient **record keeping** (+ **sorting algorithms** + **smart data structures**).

Comment: Well isnt that the very essence of computer science, to break down a problem into smaller sub-problems and then solve?

Comment: The essence of computer science is solving problems :p. The way hardware and software has evolved is through abstraction (that is solving a problem first solving its sub-problems): each component has a task and other components are going to use the components to solve other tasks. So it is a pretty common way to do things. But there are branches of computer science that do not act in this way at all. See Genetic Algorithms, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, we are solving a small problem(called subproblem) and then use it to solve bigger problems.

To achieve this we keep a record of what we have computed till now which can inturn be used next time rather than computing all over again.

Answer (score 2):

We think of a dynamic programming approach to a problem if it has

1. overlapping subproblems
2. optimal substructure

In very simple words we can say dynamic programming has two faces, they are top-down and bottom-up approaches.

In the top-down approach, we will try to write a recursive solution or a brute-force solution and memoize the results so that we will try to use that result when a similar subproblem arrives, so it is brute-force + memoization.

In the bottom-up approach, we will try to form a solution from base cases or very small subproblems where we already know the solution to. We will build the solution to the larger problem by filling a dynamic programming table that maps every combination possible giving again a brute-force template.

Coming up with a mathematical relation to the problem and also identify the above two properties is the challenging part.

### overlapping subproblems

Informally, When a problem needs the same subproblem to be solved more than once then we say it has got overlapping subproblems.

### optimal substructure

Informally, when you need to solve a problem for size n, so you divide that problem into subproblems of size n'. so now let's say it has got two stages, one stage is the problem n and another stage is the subproblems n'. Also, let's assume that you know the optimal solutions for size n' so you somehow combine these subproblem solutions together and get a solution for the size n. if the combined solution is same as the actual optimal solution for the problem of size n then you can safely say that the problem has got optimal substructure.

Let's take a simple example of finding nth Fibonacci number, to understand the two properties well.
The usual mathematical recursive relation would be

```
F(n) =  F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

Let's try to figure out the two properties for this example.
Informally, it's always easy to take a value for the size n for self-understanding.
Let n be 3 then,

```
F(3) =  F(2) + F(1)
```

We know the optimal solutions for the F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1 as base cases.

#### overlapping subproblems

```
       F(3)
       / \
      /   \
  F(2)     F(1)
   / \      / \
F(1) F(0) F(0) 0
```

From the above recursive tree you can easily find that we have to recompute F(0) and F(1) more than once. So it has got overlapping subproblems.

#### Optimal Substructure

We know the Fibonacci sequence as 0 1 1 2 ...
Let's consider a subtree as

```
  F(2)
   / \ 
F(1) F(0)
```

Combining the optimal solutions of subproblems with an addition operation would be as

```
F(2) = F(1) + F(0)
F(2) = 1 + 0
F(2) = 1
```

Combining subproblem solutions has given us the actual optimal solution solution to the problem n=2 which can be confirmed from the known Fibonacci sequence. So this problem also has an optimal substructure.

Comment: Quite nicely summarized. You mentioned that if problem has "optimal substructure" What did you mean by that. How can we determine if some problem has optimal substructure or not without knowing the solution beforehand. If you can elaborate on this that shall be great.

Comment: @gfdsal Thank you, I have updated the answer with how I go by to understand those two properties for a problem.